# Can i store database tables to a data table?

Tags: laravel, datatable

i want to store my database table in a data table is that possible?

***my controller***

```
$tablemonth = \DB::select("SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_database LIKE '%Month_Report_%'");
```

***my blade without data table***

```
<table id="listoftable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($tablemonth as $table)
    <tr>
        <td>
           {{$table->Tables_in_database}} 
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Trying to achieve like this***

```
<script>
   $(function() {
   var table = $('#listoftable').DataTable({
    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('admin.get.table') !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: {{tablemonth}}, name: {{$tablemonth}} },
    ]
   });
});
</script>
```

***Database table***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking into https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables, which allows to use the following result as input for the DataTables:

```
$data = \DB::select("SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_database LIKE '%Month_Report_%'");
return Datatables::of($data)->addIndexColumn()->make(true);
```

Create a controller using the snippet above and consume it via the following DataTables initialization:

```
<script>
         $(function() {
               $('#listoftable').DataTable({
               processing: true,
               serverSide: true,
               ajax: '{{ route('API-route-name') }}',
               columns: [
                        { data: 'Tables_in_database', name: 'Table name' }
                     ]
            });
         });
         </script>
```

See https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-datatables-tutorialexample.html for a tutorial.

Comment: thank you so much didnt know ->make(true); data tables have that

Comment: i mean i thought only model query can use data tables

Comment: The package is pretty flexible, it can handle query results and collections alltogether.

Comment: how to get DT_RowId value?

Comment: I'd suggest adding `->addIndexColumn()` to the API/PHP part, which will fill DT_RowIndex.

Comment: return Datatables::of($tablemonth)
        ->setRowId('Tables_in_database')
        ->addColumn('viewbutton', function() {
            return  "      
            <form method='post' action='{{ route('admin.printmonth.pdf') }}'>
            @csrf
          <input type='text' name='hidname' value='{{$DT_RowId}}'> 
            <button><i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o' style='color:red;'></i></button> 
        </form> "  ;
        })
->rawColumns(['viewbutton'])
->make(true);

Comment: can i put form in add column? and also how to put dt_rowid in input value with hidden attribute?

Comment: ty i figured it out